# Flexmonster - How to set DataSource from Ajax call

Tags: ajax

I want to fill the pivot with data through the result of an ajax call
I’m trying something like this, but it does not work, does not load any data.

```
        var pivot = new Flexmonster({
            container: “pivot-container”,
            componentFolder: “https://cdn.flexmonster.com/”,
            global: {
                localization: “loc/es.json”
            },
            width: “100%”,
            height: “600px”,
            report: {
                dataSource: {
                    dataSourceType: “json”,
                    data: getData()
                },
    slice: {
         rows: [{ uniqueName: “column1” }, { uniqueName: “column2” }],
                    columns: [{ uniqueName: “[column3]” }],
                    measures: [{ uniqueName: “column4” }]
                }
        });



//ajax call
//The function returns the data correctly.
    function getDatos() {
        $.ajax({
            type: “GET”,
            dataType: “json”,
            contentType: “application/json; charset=utf-8”,
            url: “api/data”,
            success: function (response) {
                return response;
            }
        });
    }
```

if I use the url in Connect => To Remote JSON it work like a charm, which indicates that the json format is correct.

How can I load the data pivot using an ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work properly, it's better to use Flexmonster’s events.
In this case, you can use the`reportcomplete` event to ensure that pivot component has been already loaded.
After that, you can run setReport API call

Another option is to load data first and after that initialize pivot object with all configurations.